# Issue with overflow and dropdown div inside of an HTML table CSS / HTML / JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, css

I cannot figure out how to allow this drop-down to expand past the boundaries of the table. I have tried applying different overflow CSS attributes to different items and changing z-index's etc to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/DWDum/

Comment: There's also an issue reported: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3287

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Fortunately my implementation does not have this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from your `div.datagrid`

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:relative;` to your dropdown-menu container.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I appreciate your help. I tried position:relative; and z-index:1000; to the drop-down container (.btn-group)

Comment: that's weird.. I'm currently looking at your files.. And was able to make it work... in the ul class dropdown-menu add the position:relative.. add !important to be sure..

Comment: That method "technically" works but if someone shrinks down their screen or views from a mobile browser the positioning of the drop-down is messed up. Look at this pic. http://i46.tinypic.com/34dk7j5.png

Comment: yeah.. i'm adding some styles to make it look better. the answer above  is better.. removing the overflow:hidden..